# Declaring Class fields for object references instead using local functions

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to understand why my teacher uses class fields all the time for references.
I believe this is to with scope, as it allows you to access that reference anywhere in the class, as oppose to declaring local variable in functions.
**Is this bad practice and is there a programming term for doing this method?** I've googled "using class fields for object reference" but I don't find much about it, so I'm not sure if developers do this a lot or just my teacher.

Below is a example of using class fields, for the object passed into constructor

```
public class UpdateStudentGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private int selectedRow;
    private JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update Student");
    private JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    
    private JTextField txtStudID = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField txtFirst = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField txtLast = new JTextField(10);
    private JPanel pnlData = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
    
    TestStudentModel parent;
    StudentTableModel studModel;  
    
    Container con;
    
    public UpdateStudentGUI(TestStudentModel fe, StudentTableModel model, Student s)
    {
        this.setTitle("Update Student");
        this.setBounds(500, 350, 300, 150);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        // ASSIGN PASSED ARGUMENT TO CLASS FIELD
        parent = fe;
        studModel = model;
        
        con = getContentPane();
        
        // add the GUI components
        pnlData.add(new JLabel("Student ID:"));
        pnlData.add(txtStudID);
        pnlData.add(new JLabel("Firstname:"));
        pnlData.add(txtFirst);
        pnlData.add(new JLabel("Lastname:"));
        pnlData.add(txtLast);
        
        con.add(pnlData, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        // add the button
        pnlButton.add(btnUpdate);
        con.add(pnlButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        
        txtStudID.setText(Integer.toString(s.getStudID()));
        txtFirst.setText(s.getFirst());
        txtLast.setText(s.getLast());
```

Comment: What would you do instead?

Comment: This looks to me like correct usage of instance fields.  What you have shown is obviously only part of the class.  The constructor is incomplete, and you have left out any methods.  If there >are< other methods ... for example, to implement the logic behind the GUI ... then they need the GUI components to be fields rather than local variables.

Comment: Maybe you are having difficulty finding something on the internet that says that this is "bad practice" because it isn't.  Likewise, you can't find a specific name for this "practice" because it is normal OO programming.  (Sometimes ... your teacher knows what he or she is talking about ...)

Comment: Specifically, I imagine that `parent = fe; studModel = model;` are there because somewhere else this class is going to make use of `parent` and `studModel`.

Comment: You can use class fields however you want. There isn't a "correct" way of using them. It is usually pretty clear when you need a field to be accessible throughout the entire class vs localized to a single method. In my opinion, if a variable is only needed in a single method, then it only clutters up the code to make it a class field. When I'm trying to understand some code, I will look at those class fields and assume they are being utilized throughout the class. Always strive to write understandable code. The only exception might be constants defined within the class.